# R - parse unaligned XML attribute to data frame

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, dataframe

I have an xml file with this structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<b>
    <c name="Foo" stuff="89" attr="First line&#xA;Second line"/>
    <c name="Bar" ID="ontime" stuff="23" attr="Blahs"/>
    <c ID="delay" name="Dog"  newattr="Clahs"/>
    ...
</b>
```

As you can see the attribute is quite messy; missing values and unaligned. I would like to convert it to the following data frame (or any other table-like structure) in R language for further analysis.

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════╗
║   name   ║ stuff        ║ attr                             ║ ID             ║ newattr ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1 Foo    ║  89          ║ "First line&#xA;Second line"     ║ NA             ║  NA     ║
║ 2 Bar    ║  23          ║ "Blahs"                          ║ "ontime"       ║  NA     ║
║ 3 Dog    ║  NA          ║      NA                          ║ "delay"        ║ "Clahs" ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════╝
```

I have failed miserably due to my limited R and parsing experience. I have a feeling `xapplySApply` may work, but couldn't figure out how to set up path.

Another technique I would like to explore is for the code to identify new attributes all by itself. In other words, no attribute's name is hard-coded in the code. For example, when it sees line 3, it automatically add new column to the data frame and name it "newattr".

Thank you very much for your help.

-------------------  ADDED on July 18, 2015  -----------------------

Here is my brute force approach. I am fairly certain there is better way to do this since it's super slow (6 hours to handle a single ~250MB xml on modern personal laptop).

```
myxmlToDataFrame2 <- function(file) {
  xL <- xmlToList(xmlParse(file))
  xL <- unname(xL)

  # initialize data frame
  df <- data.frame(t(xL[[1]]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  number_of_attribute <- length(df)
  number_of_row <- length(xL)

  for (i in 2:number_of_row) {
    # examine each element in the new row
    for (j in 1:length(xL[[i]])) {
      df[i,attributes(xL[[i]])$names[j]] <- xL[[i]][[j]]    
    }
  }
  df
}
```

Comment: can you paste a larger chunk of the file (or a link to the file) just to see if there may be anything else also wrong (and to have more to work with)?

Comment: Thank you for your fast responding. I have edited the original post to reflect the actual file content.

Answer (score 0):

We really need a complete example. `NA` data will be problematic to fill.

Here's something to get you started:

```
library(XML)

xml <- '<b>
<c name="Foo" stuff="89" attr="First line&#xA;Second line"/>
<c name="Bar" ID="ontime" stuff="23" attr="Blahs"/>
<c ID="delay" name="Dog"  attr="Clahs"/>
</b>'

xml <- xmlParse(xml)

attr_vals <- unlist(xpathApply(xmlParse(xml), "//b/c/@attr"))
stuff_vals <- unlist(xpathApply(xmlParse(xml), "//b/c/@stuff"))
ids_vals <- unlist(xpathApply(xmlParse(xml), "//b/c/@ID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `xmlAttrsToDataFrame` on the c nodes

```
XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(xml["//c"])
  name stuff                    attr     ID newattr
1  Foo    89 First line\nSecond line   <NA>    <NA>
2  Bar    23                   Blahs ontime    <NA>
3  Dog  <NA>                    <NA>  delay   Clahs
```